# How does Apple create shadow effect for a book in iBooks app in iOS 12?

Tags: ios, shadow, ibooks

I found a shadow image in the bundle of iBooks app in iOS 12. I think Apple use this image to create book's shadow, but I don't know how they do it.

[shadow image using in iBooks app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDnYX.png)

[iBooks app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DayM.jpg)

---

**My solution is scaling the shadow image to the appropriate size and put it behind the book cover image. But for cover images of different sizes, the shadow radius are different, the image below shows what it looks like, the effect is different from iBooks.**

[the shadow effect I create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb7I1.png)

This problem has troubled me for a long time, I need help.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not use the CALayer to make the shadow?  Not an image

Comment: The shadow made by CALayer is different from iBooks. In addition, I would like to know how Apple achieves this effect using a shadow image.

Comment: I doubt they use it. It was probably a placeholder for dev. You can make a shadow look any way you would like with CALayer but I will check back to see if they really did use an image. Just doubtful to me.